# Core Data crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on synchronizing contexts in mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I'm writing an iPad cookery application which is heavily based on CoreData.
In my app I have a screen for editing recipe with 2 types of information:

1. Lists with recipe category\subcategory and country
2. All other recipe-related information

Each of this list may be edited in popover. Changes of this list shall be persisted immediately (i.e. if user will add some recipe category to possible categories list, but cancels recipe creation, this category shall be available for all recipes).
It was descided to implement **2 separate NSManagedObjectContexts** to handle each type of info: **main context** for recipes management and **supporting context** for lists.

All core data operations performed via **MagicalRecord** framework. Both of contexts having MagicalRecord's default context as parent. Each context observes changes in other one. All contexts are being created and used on **main thread** so it seems that this issue has nothing related to multithreading issues.

When I'm trying to create object in support context and persist changes in support context immediately after object's creation everything going OK. The problem comes when newly created object is being deleted right after creation - EXC_BAD_ACCES received.
However, the entity is being persisted correctly and on next launch it may be used and deleted without synchronization issues.

1 note: When object is being accessed from **Main context** by existingObjectWithID: method of NSManagedObjectContext it becomes possible to delete this object. However crash happens on main context's (parent context of both Main and Supporting contexts) saving then.

Here is my code:

Entity creation:

```
RecipeCategory* category = [RecipeCategory MR_createInContext:_supportingContext];
category.name = itemName;
[_supportingContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Entity deletion:

```
[(RecipeCategory*)itemToRemove MR_deleteEntity];
[_supportingContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Contexts creation and observing setup:

```
[_mainContext MR_stopObservingContext:_supportingContext];
[_supportingContext MR_stopObservingContext:_mainContext];
_mainContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
_supportingContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
[_mainContext MR_observeContextOnMainThread:_supportingContext];
[_supportingContext MR_observeContextOnMainThread:_mainContext];
```

Please advice what may cause this issue because now I'm confused even in which way shall I move to solve this. Changes management section in Core Data documentation gives nothing. Same results gave google.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. A context watching another that is also watching the watcher...that's bad. You first need to understand the rules of nested contexts and how data flows from one to the other on save.

I your case, you may want to look for the MR_confinementContext method on NSMOC. This will create a context that uses the old thread confinement model. This may help you get around your thread crashes. But first, don't do the circular observing...data flows in

Comment: I removed circular observing of contexts. Now only main watches for changes in supporting. But this did not help, crashes are still presented. BTW I found some workaround of this issue: If for both of my contexts (main and supporting) I set parent as MR_rootSavingContext everything starts working fine. However seems it will not be a solutiin for me to use it because iCloud support also needed and MR_defaultContext is the one responsible for this.

Comment: also you pointed to rules of nested contexts and ways how data flow from each other - can you please point to some articles? Searching among google mostly gives me articles related to Core Data multithreading issues.

Comment: The best documentation, unfortunately for now, are the WWDC videos on core data. You should be able to check them out with a basic apple developer account. I would also still avoid iCloud support with core data...it's pretty bad at their point...